# CORS + Windows Authentication not playing nice with Edge or IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors, microsoft-edge

I've having a CORS issue that only happens in Edge and IE11. Chrome works fine.

My setup is an ASP.NET MVC5 app (client) that has a script calling out to a separate ASP.NET MVC5 app (API) that only contains WebAPI controllers. Security in both apps is through Windows Authentication.

Currently, everything is running on localhost during development.

When the client script makes the call to the API, the OPTIONS preflight works fine. However, when the `GET` happens, Edge and IE get the following error:

[image]

In this image, `localhost:50281` is the client, and `localhost:47205` is the API.

Something that is weird, is that the call isn't actually hitting the controller. The controller is decorated with a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`, and a breakpoint in there doesn't ever get hit.

## Here is how CORS is set up in the API project:

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:50281");
        // Yes, there are too many headers. I've been working on this a while, and there are a few overkill options that have crept in
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-AspNet-Version,X-Powered-By,Date,Server,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cache-Control,Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Pragma,Referer,User-Agent");
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS");
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "600");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:50281", "*", "*");
    cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
    cors.PreflightMaxAge = 600;
    config.EnableCors(cors);
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

## Here is the script function in the client project:

```
GetStatus = () => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: apiUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: (result) => {
            this.Status(result);
        }
    });
}
```

## Update

I modified Global.asax.cs to ensure that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials are included with every request, as was suggested. However, this still results in a 401 only in Edge and IE. It works fine in Chrome.

## Update 2

I guess something did change. I missed that the error is now reduced to the following:
[image]

This is obviously from me getting the appropriate headers in place. However, for some reason, Edge and IE are still not letting the authentication pass through, despite the presence of `withCredentials: true`. Is there another piece I'm missing?

Comment: Do you use owin?

Comment: @anılyıldırım Yes

Comment: @kettch did you get this fixed?

I'm starting to believe its not possible
Ref: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a8dd1193-d1e7-4c9d-8d0a-7e6e82536a19/edge-browser-and-pass-through-authentication?forum=win10itprogeneral

Comment: @IsaackRasmussen Sorry, I've been distracted with another priority. I'll circle back around to this one today and double check the posted answers.

Answer (score 3):

**ASP.NET (OWIN)**

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors
```

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
```

Web Config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (ACAO) and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` (ACAC) headers with the GET request as well as with the preflight OPTIONS request. Those two headers need to be returned for every cross-domain request where you're passing cookies/authentication.

Best/simplest/cleanest way is to code so that, for ALL requests (OPTIONS, GET, POST etc.) which include the Origin request header add the ACAO and ACAC headers. Then, for OPTIONS requests, **also** add the other Access-Control-Allow-* headers...

Also, FWIW, it's a wise idea to return the value of the Origin request header in the ACAO header, rather than hardcode it as `http://localhost:50281`. That way, if you change your port or whatever, it will still function.

Comment: I made sure that the headers are present, but it doesn't seem to change the outcome.